# Where is the code describing IBOutlet and IBAction connections?

Tags: cocoa-touch, xib, ibaction, iboutlet

When connecting a UI object to an outlet using Interface Builder's drag and drop functionality, what code is generated to describe that connection? Which file contains the code? What about `IBAction` connections?

Comment: What i was confused is which codes describe the connection between those two objects. The code generated in the .h and .m files didn't do the connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interface Builder does not generate Objective-C code, though the things you are talking about can be done in code.  IB creates XML files (.xib) which are compiled to binary .nib files.

Connections to UI outlets simply represent assignment to properties or ivars.

Connections of events to actions can be created with code.  If you have an `IBAction` on object foo that you want to be triggered by `UIButton *bar`'s Touch Up Inside event, you would do the following:

```
 [bar addTarget:foo
      action:@selector(tappedButton:)
      forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thanks. That answers my question. I guessed there was something in the nib file too.